# Can someone help me with this error in C?

Tags: c

Can someone help me with below code? Ever I run it i get the follow error:

```
malloc(): corrupted top size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I searched the problematic line and the last printf is the problem, how I solve it and why this occurs? I dont know what to do. I searched this error and maybe is a allocation problem, but I have space allocated enough. Thank you :D

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    double pivo, soma, mult, xp, resp;
    int k, n, p;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    double *x = (double *) malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double *tmp = (double *) malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double **a = (double **) malloc(n * sizeof(double *));

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = (double *) malloc(n * sizeof(double));

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) scanf("%lf %lf", &x[i], &a[i][n]);
    scanf("%lf", &xp);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) a[i][j] = pow(x[i], j);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        pivo = a[i][i];
        p = i;
        
        for(int k = i+1; k < n; k++)

        if(fabs(pivo) < fabs(a[k][i])){
            pivo = a[k][i];
            p = k;
        }

        for(int j = 0; j <= n; j++){
            tmp[j] = a[p][j];
            a[p][j] = a[i][j];
            a[i][j] = tmp[j];
        }

        for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++){
            mult = a[j][i]/a[i][i];
            for(int k = 0;k <= n; k++) a[j][k] -= mult * a[i][k];       
        }
    }


    for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        soma = 0;
        for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++) soma += a[i][j] * tmp[j];
        tmp[i] = (a[i][n] - soma) / a[i][i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        resp = resp + (tmp[i] * pow(xp, i));
    }

    printf("%lf\n", resp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This line: `tmp[i] = (a[i][n] - soma) / a[i][i];` is a problem. Is it a typo? (You can't access element 'n' of an array sized `n`.) Not sure what the second index should be, though.

Comment: if you add a  "printf("%lf\n", resp);" before of  "scanf("%d", &n);" this error not occur

Comment: Hmmm. But, once you have entered the land of Undefined Behaviour, then anything can happen and all other code-bets are off. Accessing that `[n]` element will cross the frontier of that fabled land.

Comment: hmmm try run this code here https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

Comment: Just fix the obvious error (and it *is* an error). What else can I say?

Comment: You should try using a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two places where you are writing outside the memory you malloc'd.

```
&a[i][n]                     // should be &a[i][n-1], I assume
for(int j = 0; j <= n; j++)  // should be `j < n`
```

I've heard this is called "planting landmines" because you may not get an immediate error (but [*undefined behavior*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)). The error occurs when the landmine is stepped on, which may be further down the track, long after the original error was first made.

Comment: "_which may be further down the track, long after the original error was first made_" - or even before it, looking at the code as a sequence of events.